# divide ethers error

Tags: ether, ethers.js

i get "RangeError: too many decimals for format" error running the following code :

const Amount = 0.001
const targetPrice = 0.9152;
const sellAmount =  ethers.parseUnits(`${Amount / targetPrice}`, 'ether');